# Log out from facebook using the facebook c# sdk on windows 8 App (metro app)?

Tags: c#, facebook, cookies, windows-8

I have finished integrating Facebook in my metro app ,the problem is when i logout i can logout and exit , but when i login the next time , it logins in automatically with the previously used details and logins in as the previous user .

The solution to this for Windows Phone 8 is by clearing the cookies in the WebBrowser Data .
The Code for that is :

```
await new WebBrowser().ClearCookiesAsync();
```

I want a solution to the same problem for Windows 8 Metro App , like is there is a similar way to clear the cookies , if so , how ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this to logout 
 FacebookSessionClient.Logout();

Comment: i first logout by using FacebookSessionClient.Logout(); and then redirect to my login view and again login its works fine